# Disabling Number Presses In DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

How can I make it so if you press a number while selecting a DateTimePicker, it won't modify the value?

Currently, I have an onKeyDown to catch all numbers, and set e.Handled = true, but that still doesn't seem to override it.

Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this? What do you have against people who would rather use the keyboard than a mouse?

Comment: The DateTimePicker has some date changing functionality that is controlled by arrow presses, so it still does have some keyboard control.  Although I do agree with you that it would be best to keep the number functionality in, this is purely a request from a higher up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the OnKeyPress event instead:

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  e.Handled = true;
  base.OnKeyPress(e);
}
```

or if just using the current DateTimePicker without creating your own control:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

The arrow keys should still work.

Comment: For some reason when I put some code in my DateTimePicker_KeyPress even, the code is never reached when I actually press a key.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @sooprise It sounds like you might be overriding the `OnKeyPress` method and NOT passing the `base.OnKeyPress(e)`?  Otherwise, no, I'm not sure what you are doing.  My little example worked on a new form.  Pressing arrow keys worked, pressing numbers and letters did not change the date.

Comment: Agh, I'm such a noob, I didn't understand what was going on in your post.  Thanks for that extra explanation! :)

Comment: One last thing, this override is for OnKeyPress in general, so this is going to affect any control I have an OnKeyPress event?

Comment: @sooprise The OnKeyPress is for the custom control, where you created a new DateTimePicker based on inheriting from the existing DateTimePicker control.  Where ever you use that control, the KeyPress event will be automatically handled.  If you don't want that, then you don't need a custom control-- just handle the event of the control on the form like in the second example.  Hope that's clear.